# What's a nifty way to restrict my dog run without re-installing it?

Tags: lawn, lead

We have a "dog run" in our back yard that we hook our dogs to when they need to go out. Their harnesses hook to a lead, and then lead in turn hooks to the wheel you see in the picture below. The wheel runs along a line that is about 40 feet in length. This way, they can run around the entire back yard (pretty much) without restriction, but are still bound by the run.

[image]

The problem is, one end of this run (the line you see the wheel running along) is sunk (drilled) into a tree, and my dogs **always** end up wrapping themselves around the tree. I've finally had it! I'm sick of having to put on my boots and tread some 50 feet out into my back yard to unhook them and unwind the lead from around the tree. The time has finally come for me to find a solution that prevents them from wrapping around the tree.

I've thought about putting up some kind of fence that hooks into the tree (that way they can't wrap around it), but this tree is smack dab in the center of our lawn and anything I put up will be an eyesore for my wife.

Also, this lead was a real pain to put up, so I'd like to avoid taking it down and reinstalling it at all costs.

So now I'm considering putting something on the run itself; some kind of block that prevents them from getting to the tree in the first place. This would limit their run from about 40 feet to 30 feet, but I don't think that will rob them of any exercise.

But if I just simply wind duck tape around the run, the first time they go running after a squirrel or something, the wheel will get lodged on the duck tape and then they'll be stuck in the center of the lawn; plus I'll have to go un-lodge them.

So I ask: can any DIYers out there think of a way that I can:

1. Attach something to my dog run that will hold resolute but not allow the wheel to get lodged or wedged on it; and
2. Not require me to take the run down and put it back up

Comment: is the line nylon/rope, or a cable?  Browse around your local hardware megastore and you will probably find a variety of stays and clamps that you can attach to a cable.  They may also work with a rope.  Another option might be to take a length of PVC or garden hose, slit it to slide over the rope, and use that to create a stop before they reach the tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They make clamps that you can very easily install onto the line. They come in a range of sizes to fit most any line size. Here is a picture of what they look like.

[image]

You can procure these at most home supply centers and at any decent hardware store. Look for Steel Cable clamps.

There is another type of connector that may be an alternate choice. These, as pictured below, will be found in the electrical supply section of the same types of stores mentioned above. They are typically made of copper and so will not rust. Price will be a little higher though.

[image]

Comment: no doubt these will work great, but the sheave ("wheel") pictured is made of plastic, and will probably get beat up by any metal stopper pretty quickly. It may be best therefore to buy an all-metal pulley to replace the existing "wheel" with as well.

Answer (score 5):

You could get a u-shaped rope clamp.

Comment: It's a good answer but it would be more helpful if you can provide a photo (or a link to a photo) to clarify exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Get or make two small identical blocks of wood, put the rope between them, and bolt them together with two bolts on opposite sides of the rope. This will clamp solidly onto the rope, be easily adjustable by loosening the bolts, and present a large flat surface for the wheel to stop against without jamming.

You might want to round over the edge where the rope meets the wood to reduce the possibility of fraying.